# Thymeleaf parameters don't change in recursive fragment calls

Tags: html, thymeleaf

While building a recursive fragment in thymeleaf I noticed the value of the parameter does not change. Here is a simple example:

**Java**

```
ctx = new WebContext(request, response, servletContext);
ctx.setVariable("var1", "1");
ctx.setVariable("var2", "2");
```

**Html**

```
<div th:fragment="test ( parameter )">
    <p th:text="${parameter}"></p>
    <div th:if="${'__${parameter}__' == '1'}">
        <p th:replace="fragments :: test ( ${var2} )"></p>
    </div>
</div>

<div th:replace="fragments :: test ( ${var1} )></div>
```

Which results in stackoverflow. After some debugging I found out that the value of `parameter` is `1` at every cycle.

Why is this happening and what is the workaround?

Comment: Your fragment seems to work for me. Can you share how you're calling it in the first place? And perhaps a small sample data set?

Comment: @Andrew I edited the question and put a much simpler recurse function with the same result for me.